# Metrizable weak topology of closed ball in $c_0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

It is well known that if $X$ is a Banach space and $X^*$ contains separating sequence (i.e. sequence $(f_n) \subset X^{*}$ such that $f_n x = 0$, $n = 1,2, \dots$, implies that $x=0$) and $K \subset X$ is weakly compact then $K$ is weakly metrizable (i.e. metrizable in weak topology).

Using this we can easily prove, for example, that closed unit ball $B$ in $\ell^p$, $1 < p < \infty$, is weakly metrizable. Indeed, $\ell^p$ is reflexive and hence $B$ is weakly compact, which follows from Banach-Alaoglu theorem (it is even equivalent; closed unit ball is weakly compact if and only if $X$ is reflexive). Moreover $\ell^p$ contains separating sequence, thus $B$ is metrizable.

Can we prove that closed unit ball $B_{c_0}$ in $c_0$ is weakly metrizable? Main problem here is that $c_0$ is not reflexive and we can't mimic previous argument.

Comment: $c_o$? Could you explain this notation?

Comment: @Elias: This is the space of real sequences converging to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend your statement as follows: Let $X$ be a seperable normed space, then every (norm-)bounded subset of $X^*$ is metrizable in the relative weak*-topology.
Now apply this to $X=l^1$. Then $B_{c_0}$ as a bounded subset of $l^\infty$ is metrizable in the relative weak*-topology $\sigma(l^\infty, l^1)$ which is equal to $\sigma(c_0,l^1)$.

Comment: What is meant by $\sigma(l^\infty, l^1)$?  I keep running into this notation but cant find an explanation :0

Comment: @N00ber For a normed space $X$ you should know the weak*-topology on the continuous dual $X^\star$. This topology is sometimes denoted as $\sigma(X^\star, X)$, the weakest topology on $X^\star$, such that the evaluation mappings $x^\star \mapsto x^\star(x)$ for $x \in X$ are continuous. The $\sigma$-symbol comes from the german expression for "weak", which is "schwach", so starts with the letter "s", the greek $\sigma$.  Now you can consider a subspace $Y$ of $X^\star$. The subspace topology of $\sigma(X^\star, X)$ restricted to $Y$ is denoted by $\sigma(Y,X)$.

Comment: For the general theory on dual topologies see a textbook like Treves, Topological Vector Spaces and Kernels.

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much :)